# Synchronization in clustered environment

Tags: java, tomcat, synchronization, cluster-computing, load-balancing

We are in the process of going from a single tomcat to two clustered tomcat instances with load balancing and session replication. Before we can do that we have to make some adjustments to some existing code: We have some background jobs running with various intervals, and we only want these jobs to run once (not on both tomcat nodes). Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with the [Quartz framework](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering) and clustering option using a JDBCJobStore.

> "Load-balancing occurs automatically, with each node of the cluster firing jobs as quickly as it can. When a trigger's firing time occurs, the first node to acquire it (by placing a lock on it) is the node that will fire it. Only one node will fire the job for each firing."

You just have to create three tables holding the job/task information. All Tomcat nodes will access these tables. Once a job is fired, the first able node will execute the task, the others wont. If one node fails the task, another one may retry it.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this. Does this work with a MSSQL database?

Comment: Yes, works with any db that can be accessed by JDBC.